# How to make array from input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array in txt file and read this with

```
   fs.readFileSync("./input.txt")
```

When i wrap it in console.log i get(since it is written in the file itself):

```
    1 2 3 
    100 5000
```

I would have the array:

```
['1','2','3','100','5000']
```

Placement of the array in the input file should not change.
Suggest how to do it, please.

Comment: Do `const numbers = fs.readFileSync("./input.txt");` so you have the content stored in a string variable. The next step is to split() this string at a space or linebreak character. Split supports regular expressions, so there's all the building blocks you need to solve this yourself. Or you can just wait for the overeager answers to solve this for you so you will learn nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to split words: `\w+`

```js
let a = `    1 2 3 
    100 5000 `;
    
console.log(a.match(/\w+/g))
```

To read your file and split it:

```js
fs.readFileSync("./input.txt").match(/\w+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, load it then, split by lines, then on each line split by space then flatten it, then filter out empty values.

```js
let str = `1 2 3 
    100 5000 0`; // added 0 to show filter(Boolean) wont remove
    
console.log(str.split('\n').map(v => v.split(' ')).flat().filter(Boolean))
```

Result:

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "100",
  "5000",
  "0"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by a space, then filter out the falsy items in the resulting array.

```js
const input = `    1 2 3 
    100 5000 `;

let res = input.split(" ").filter(e => e.trim())
console.log(res)
```